# PHP Parse.com Export table into a CSV file

Tags: php, database, csv, parse-platform, export

I am new to Parse.com & learning as I go, does anyone know if it is at all possible to query data from Parse.com & then export it into a CSV file using PHP?

My parse.com query is as follows:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Counter");
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$result = $query->find();
print_r($result);
```

this gives me all of my data, I need to take all of this into a csv file.

I know that parse.com has a 1 click function that allows you to get the data from the table, however I need to build a function on my site that does this so clients have it available to them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

Here is a snippit of the output (It outputs 159 records, so I have only included the first few).

```
Array ( [0] => Parse\ParseObject Object ( [serverData:protected] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Covers [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => l6rKi7qpFX [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-12 00:40:58.178000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-12 00:40:58.178000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) [1] => Parse\ParseObject Object ( [serverData:protected] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Covers [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => pKAhO2o9Yp [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-12 00:40:57.309000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-12 00:40:57.309000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) [2] => Parse\ParseObject Object ( [serverData:protected] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [covers] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Covers [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 6q17n3FFyX [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-12 00:40:56.453000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z )
```

Comment: can you show us what print_r($result)  outputs ?

Comment: Hi Nassim, I haved added an extract of the output, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will help but you can try it

```
<?php

$query = new ParseQuery("Counter");
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$result = $query->find();
//print_r($result);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but doesn't seem to work - I expanded on it as well because I wasn't getting any output & used the following, but still no joy: 

$fp = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=dboutput.csv"); 

foreach($result as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp) or die("Can't close php://output");

Comment: just to add, I managed to generate the CSV file, however it just does not contain any of the data, so it seems to be a gap between the $result & generating the CSV file

Comment: @CBalicki the thing is that it's a mixed and nested array , that means it has nested objects inside array elements, you will have to use foreach loop on each nesting level. sorry about that